# JQuery ToolTip: How to have 2 different styles?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have the jquery-tooltip from here:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Not I have this code:

```
.tooltip 
{
display:none;
background:transparent url(/Images/Design/Tooltip/black_arrow.png);
font-size:12px;
height:70px;
width:160px;
padding:25px;
color:#fff; 
}  

<asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="Tooltip" Title="Tragen Sie bitte hier Ihre Branche ein - z.B. Friseur, Anwalt, KFZ Werkstatt..." ID="imgHelp1" ImageUrl="~/Images/Design/Icons/question1.gif"
                            Height="15" />

 <asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="Tooltip" Title="Tragen Sie hier bitte 'Suchworte' ein mit denen Sie gefunden werden möchten. Z.B.
                                    wenn Sie ein Friseur sind: Haare schneiden, Haare färben, Ihren Firmennamen..." ID="imgHelp2" ImageUrl="~/Images/Design/Icons/question1.gif"
                            Height="15" />

$('.Tooltip').tooltip();
```

For the first image, the tooltip-height or 70px is perfect.
For the second image, the tooltip-height must be at least 100px.

But how do that? How can I have 2 different styles of the tooltip itself or give the tooltip a classname within or such like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is:

name: tipClass
Default: 'tooltip'

Since 1.2.0. CSS class name for the generated tooltip element.